# Anyone got a WPF features history

Tags: wpf, history

We're in the process of moving into WPF (going very nicely thankyou) and the last work I did with it was a couple of years ago so most of the books I've got from that time frame are little dated.

Has anyone got a list of "new" features for WPF that have been added since the v1 release? In many ways its the little stuff like stringformat in a binding which got introduced in WPF 3.5 SP1 that are easy to miss and since I've been "away" I've no idea what got added while I wasn't looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of obvious links from Microsoft:

[Version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx) & [Version 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(VS.100).aspx)

Also some recommended blogs:

[Lester's WPF Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/default.aspx)

[Karl on WPF](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/)

[WindowsClient.NET](http://windowsclient.net/)

Comment: Close but ideally I was looking for a single list from V1. (I should have mentioned that I'd found the 3.5 list already)

Comment: There was no "WPF" V1.  WPF was first included in NET Framework at NET Framework version 3.0.  Before that it was named "Avalon" or "WinFX".  So if you studied books and other materials on "WPF", they will have been for 3.0 or later.

Comment: Ah thanks for that Ray. I hate it when version numbers get synched like that it.

Answer (score 0):

Not much...The only things I can think of are:

- [MS Open Source WPF DataGrid](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf)
- [MVVM gains traction as "the pattern" for WPF development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Of course some changes in [WPF 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/26/wpf-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), but none of them are really a game changer.